# Why is the direction of $I$ or $F$ different in case of Motors and Generators?

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

1. In the first diagram, the wire is carrying current into the screen. Motion of the wire is downwards (**Left Hand Rule**)
2. In the second diagram, the wire is moved downwards, and a current is induced, flowing out of the screen (**Right Hand Rule**)

In both cases, the direction of motion is the same (downwards) but the direction of Current is opposite.

When we compare the Right and Left Hand Rules, we find that there is always one of the three, either Current, Magnetic Field, or Force (Motion), who's direction is changing. Why does this happen?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Why do we apply Fleming's *left* hand rule in case of DC motors but use Fleming's *right* hand rule in case of generators?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145323/why-do-we-apply-flemings-left-hand-rule-in-case-of-dc-motors-but-use-fleming).

Comment: But there's no answer posted there. It didn't get much attention.

Comment: I've never used any "left hand rule". I don't really like this kind of rules because the user doesn't usually think about physics while using it. In this case, I really don't understand the figure, sorry.

Comment: @TZDZ Please don't joke here. The grey and red circle is the wire cross section, and arrows represent the direction of $B$-field

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably stupid, but why is there an induced current ? Is it an infinite wire ?

Comment: Here's a 3d view. I couldn't illustrate any better. [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wjaMQ.png)

Comment: Here are the only induced currents I can think of : [link](http://i.imgur.com/WzGm15e.png)